# Cannot find reference '_siftdown' in 'heapq.pyi'

Tags: python-3.x, heap

I cannot find anyone with the same problem here on stackoverflow.

I have imported heapq and I am trying to do heapq._siftup() but it says it cannot find the reference to it?

I know I'm doing it right because I am following a solution to a problem, why is it giving me an error?

My interpreter is python 3.8

Comment: Just try to run and it works fine. Can you show your code?

Comment: you're right it works even though there's a yellow highlight